# asp.net rewrite a select rendering code

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i make this code better and shorter?

```
<select id="products" name="products" multiple="multiple">
        <% foreach (var item in Model.Products){%>
        <option value="<%= item.Id%>" 
         <% if (item.isAvailable)
            {
              response.write("selected='selected'");
            }
          %> >
           <%= item.Name%>
         </option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
```

Comment: if it does what you want, why do you feel the need to change it?

Comment: Is there a performance problem that you are seening..? what's wrong with the code that you have currently..? are you getting errors >>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `response.write` here:

```
<option value="<%= item.Id%>" <% if (item.isAvailable) { %> selected="selected" <% } %>><%= item.Name%></option>
```